# datetimepicker control

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

which event should be fired when the user selects some date in the DateTimePickerControl ? I used dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged () . But it does get fired even when the user scroll through the date time picker.

I only want to get it fired only when user makes some change. Like a combobox selectionchagedcommitted event.

Comment: When you are scrolling through your `DateTimePicker` you are actually changing the value of your control. If you want to only trigger it when the date is clicked on then you should probably be using the `CloseUp` Event and use the Checked property to see if you have a proper value.

Comment: Did you check and ensure that DateTimePicker is hooked to the ValueChanged event? I just tried it with the same event and the value is diplsayed when a date is selected or scrolled through.
        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                    MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
        }

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx). Especially, the **OnValueChanged**
event

You will need to wire your control up using this event:

In a constructor method:

```
dateTimePickerControl.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(picker_ValueChanged);
```

And here is the method signature:

```
void f_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do whatever you need when the value changes here
}
```

You can also do this from the designer. If you go to the Properties, then Events portion, it lists all of the events. Just double click and it will create the method signature and wiring for you.

UPDATE TO YOUR UPDATE

If you specifically want to check whether this is a programmatic change or not, then you want to do something like this:

Create a global variable in your class

```
     Boolean isProgrammaticEvent = false;
```

Before your programmatic change:

```
  isProgrammaticEvent = true;
//Change picker value
```

In your event wiring:

```
 void f_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Boolean isThisProgrammatic = isProgrammaticEvent;
    isProgrammaticEvent = false;
    if(isThisProgrammatic)
        return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try at **MouseCaptureChanged(**).It wont fire while scrolling

```
private void dateTimePicker1_MouseCaptureChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime result = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());

        }
```